# Input Event Tracker

Tags: android, events

in my project, i am needed to capture the view which is corresponding to the event (event can be touch, click, or any event applicable). I think the best approach is not by injecting some-kind-of-detecting-mechanism. what i need to know is how to do that without refactoring all the listeners created before because i am advised to not change what has been created. or if it is not possible, what is the simplest solution to do this?

so far i am able to capture the ViewId from Activity by detecting the coordinate of touch event then check the child of the layout in loop.

```
//I put this in Activity
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d("DISPATCH",ev.getRawX()+","+ev.getRawY());
    if(layout!=null){
        for(int _numChildren = 0; _numChildren<((ViewGroup)layout).getChildCount();_numChildren++)
        {
            View _child = ((ViewGroup)layout).getChildAt(_numChildren);
            Log.d("CHILD ID",_child.getId()+"");
            Rect _bounds = new Rect();
            _child.getHitRect(_bounds);

            if (isPointInsideView(ev.getRawX(),ev.getRawY(),_child))
                try {
                    Log.d("VIEW CAPTURED",_child.getResources().getResourceName(_child.getId()));
                    tv.setText(_child.getResources().getResourceName(_child.getId()));
                    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

http://pierrchen.blogspot.com/2014/03/pipeline-of-android-touch-event-handling.html

from this link, i believe that the touch event will be dispatched from activity to corresponding listener which i was able to capture, but is it posible to detect the view itself as the event handling flow is going back to top(Activity)?

fyi the listeners are located in many fragments, activities and custom views.

thanks, any help is really appreciated.

edit: if you have better approach/idea about this please lead me up, i am open for better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the regular onTouchListener, wherein in the onTouch method you can check for the type of touch happening.... 
Eg.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (mViewWidth < 2) {
            mViewWidth = mRecyclerView.getWidth();
        }

        switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
              //Do something here
              break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
              //Do something here
              break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
              //Do something here
              break;
        }
        }
         ........
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where can i put this so i can detect all the events (event tracker)? if i need to put this in every view that need a listener then it is the least solution i will try :) anyway thanks for noticing

Comment: What I would suggest is make an abstract touch listener class(by subclassing the android base touch listener) and wherever you are creating a listener for touch, extend this abstract listener class. In the abstract touch listener you can capture the events in a single place.